# apache, serving outside

Tags: apache-2.2, debian, remote-access, django

Greetings
I have a local development machine that connects internet from an ADSL router. I want to let a person on the internet to access the local apache server (under Ubuntu) to see my site (which I can access via typing 127.0.0.1 at my browser)

I have tried to enter my machine by typing my IP, it asked me username and password (I do not know if it is related with adsl modem or some password for apache)

How can I achieve this ?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do a port forwarding on the router. If you have an ADSL modem it is possible that it behaving as an router and you have to do port forwarding in both equipments.

You will have to forward port TCP/80 for HTTP and, maybe, TCP/443 for HTTPS.

If you give more details we can give you more precise answers.

- what is the brand and model of your router?
- do you have a modem and a router, or only one network equipment?
- do you have firewall or other filtering software on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Mircea's answer, once you get port-forwarding correctly setup, you'll need make sure to give your external IP (http://whereismyip.com/) to other people so they can access your site. You may also want to look at using a dynamic dns service like dyndns.com.